# File-local variables do not affect org-babel-execute

Tags: org-babel, file-local-variables

I am trying to compile a org block with latex using `org-babel` and I set some local variables

```
 # local variables:
 # org-latex-pdf-process: ("lualatex -output-directory=%o %f")
 # org-format-latex-header: \\documentclass[class=book]{standalone}
 # org-latex-default-packages-alist: ()
 # org-latex-packages-alist: (("" "myfonts" t))
 # end:
```

The block is:

```
#+begin_src latex :results graphics file :file ./prova.pdf
  \sf

  Hello world!

#+end_src
```

However, when I compile the block, `org-execute-babel:latex` is partially unaware of my local settings. Namely, it uses `lualatex` as a compiler and sets `\documentclass` as required, but neither `org-latex-default-packages-alist` nor `org-latex-packages-alist` take  the value I set in local variables during the compilation of the `.tex` file.

Comment: You are missing double quotes around the value of `org-format-latex-header`: it's supposed to be a string. But even with that, the production of the intermediate TeX file happens in a different (temporary) buffer, so the local values you have set in the Org mode buffer are disregarded and the global values are used instead. That might qualify as a bug: `org-babel-execute:latex` certainly starts in the Org mode buffer, so it could retrieve those values and squirrel them away to use later. Maybe submit a bug report to the [Org mode ML](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-mailing-list.html)?

Comment: Thank you. In meanwhile, can you suggest a workaround? (Some hacking of the function `org-babel-execute:latex`)

Comment: I've provided (somewhat reluctantly) a workaround in the answer below, but I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

First here's a simplified version of the problem. Consider this Org mode file:

```el
#+begin_src elisp
  (setq-default foo "bar")
  (defun func()
    (princ foo )
    (with-temp-buffer "*tmp-foo*"
       (princ foo)))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: func

#+begin_src elisp :results output
  (func)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: barbar
```

The first code block sets the default value of a variable and defines a function that prints the value of that variable in two different contexts: the first one is in the context of the Org mode buffer and the second is in the context of some temporary buffer that the function creates for its own purposes. The second code block calls that function. As you can see from its results, the value in both contexts is the string `bar`, i.e. the global value of the variable.

We can add a local variables section and close/reopen the Org mode file to activate the local variable setting (or execute `M-x normal mode` which will also activate the local variable setting), so now the Org mode file and its buffer look like this:

```el
#+begin_src elisp
  (setq-default foo "bar")
  (defun func()
    (princ foo )
    (with-temp-buffer "*tmp-foo*"
       (princ foo)))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: func

#+begin_src elisp :results output
  (func)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: bazbar


* Local variables
# Local variables:
# foo: "baz"
# end:
```

Now when we evaluate the second block (the one that calls the function), we see that the first `princ` (the one that is done in the context of the Org mode buffer where the buffer-local binding of `foo` is in force) prints out `baz`, but the second one (the one that is done in the context of the temporary buffer) prints out `bar`, the global value of `foo` - there is no buffer-local setting of `foo` in the temporary buffer.

One way to make the function use the buffer-local binding in both contexts is to save the buffer-local binding in a local variable (of the *function*, not of the buffer) using a `let` and then use that saved value in the temp buffer context:

```el
#+begin_src elisp
  (setq-default foo "bar")
  (defun func()
    (let ((f0 foo))
      (princ foo )
      (with-temp-buffer "*tmp-foo*"
                        (let ((foo f0))
                          (princ foo)))))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: func

#+begin_src elisp :results output
  (func)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: bazbaz


* Local variables
# Local variables:
# foo: "baz"
# end:
```

Now we get `baz` in both contexts. Note that by using the second `let` to set the value of `foo` *inside* the body of `with-temp-buffer`, we don't have to modify the rest of the body: it was using `foo` before and it is still using `foo` afterwards, but we have switched the value from under it.

That's the idea behind this modification of `org-babel-execute:latex`. It's just that there is more code, but most of is unchanged: the difference is that we have a `let` before the `with-temp-buffer` to save the (possibly buffer-local) values of several variables and then another `let` *after* the `with-temp-buffer` to define new local variables that have the same name as before, but they get their values from the saved local variables before we enter the temp-buffer context. The changed lines have trailing comments to indicate that: you'll have to scroll down to about the three-quarter mark to find them; the rest are exactly the same as before except for indentation.

```el
(defun org-babel-execute:latex (body params)
  "Execute a block of Latex code with Babel.
This function is called by `org-babel-execute-src-block'."
  (setq body (org-babel-expand-body:latex body params))
  (if (cdr (assq :file params))
      (let* ((out-file (cdr (assq :file params)))
             (extension (file-name-extension out-file))
             (tex-file (org-babel-temp-file "latex-" ".tex"))
             (border (cdr (assq :border params)))
             (imagemagick (cdr (assq :imagemagick params)))
             (im-in-options (cdr (assq :iminoptions params)))
             (im-out-options (cdr (assq :imoutoptions params)))
             (fit (or (cdr (assq :fit params)) border))
             (height (and fit (cdr (assq :pdfheight params))))
             (width (and fit (cdr (assq :pdfwidth params))))
             (headers (cdr (assq :headers params)))
             (in-buffer (not (string= "no" (cdr (assq :buffer params)))))
             (org-latex-packages-alist
              (append (cdr (assq :packages params)) org-latex-packages-alist)))
        (cond
         ((and (string-suffix-p ".png" out-file) (not imagemagick))
          (let ((org-format-latex-header
                 (concat org-format-latex-header "\n"
                         (mapconcat #'identity headers "\n"))))
            (org-create-formula-image
             body out-file org-format-latex-options in-buffer)))
         ((string= "svg" extension)
          (with-temp-file tex-file
            (insert (concat (funcall org-babel-latex-preamble params)
                            (mapconcat #'identity headers "\n")
                            (funcall org-babel-latex-begin-env params)
                            body
                            (funcall org-babel-latex-end-env params))))
          (let ((tmp-pdf (org-babel-latex-tex-to-pdf tex-file)))
            (let* ((log-buf (get-buffer-create "*Org Babel LaTeX Output*"))
                   (err-msg "org babel latex failed")
                   (img-out (org-compile-file
                             tmp-pdf
                             (list org-babel-latex-pdf-svg-process)
                             extension err-msg log-buf)))
              (shell-command (format "mv %s %s" img-out out-file)))))
         ((string-suffix-p ".tikz" out-file)
          (when (file-exists-p out-file) (delete-file out-file))
          (with-temp-file out-file
            (insert body)))
         ((and (string= "html" extension)
               (executable-find org-babel-latex-htlatex))
          ;; TODO: this is a very different way of generating the
          ;; frame latex document than in the pdf case.  Ideally, both
          ;; would be unified.  This would prevent bugs creeping in
          ;; such as the one fixed on Aug 16 2014 whereby :headers was
          ;; not included in the SVG/HTML case.
          (with-temp-file tex-file
            (insert (concat
                     "\\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\\def\\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht.def}
"
                     (mapconcat (lambda (pkg)
                                  (concat "\\usepackage" pkg))
                                org-babel-latex-htlatex-packages
                                "\n")
                     (if headers
                         (concat "\n"
                                 (if (listp headers)
                                     (mapconcat #'identity headers "\n")
                                   headers) "\n")
                       "")
                     "\\begin{document}"
                     body
                     "\\end{document}")))
          (when (file-exists-p out-file) (delete-file out-file))
          (let ((default-directory (file-name-directory tex-file)))
            (shell-command (format "%s %s" org-babel-latex-htlatex tex-file)))
          (cond
           ((file-exists-p (concat (file-name-sans-extension tex-file) "-1.svg"))
            (if (string-suffix-p ".svg" out-file)
                (progn
                  (shell-command "pwd")
                  (shell-command (format "mv %s %s"
                                         (concat (file-name-sans-extension tex-file) "-1.svg")
                                         out-file)))
              (error "SVG file produced but HTML file requested")))
           ((file-exists-p (concat (file-name-sans-extension tex-file) ".html"))
            (if (string-suffix-p ".html" out-file)
                (shell-command "mv %s %s"
                               (concat (file-name-sans-extension tex-file)
                                       ".html")
                               out-file)
              (error "HTML file produced but SVG file requested")))))
         ((or (string= "pdf" extension) imagemagick)
          ;; Save global/buffer-local values
          (let ((o1 org-format-latex-header)           ; <--ADDED
                (o2 org-latex-pdf-process)             ; <--ADDED
                (o3 org-latex-default-packages-alist)  ; <--ADDED
                (o4 org-latex-packages-alist))         ; <--ADDED
            (with-temp-file tex-file
              ;; Set the new, local variables with the old names from
              ;; the saved values and then use the old names without
              ;; any further change.
              (let ((org-format-latex-header o1)           ; <--ADDED
                    (org-latex-pdf-process o2)             ; <--ADDED
                    (org-latex-default-packages-alist o3)  ; <--ADDED
                    (org-latex-packages-alist o4))         ; <--ADDED
                (require 'ox-latex)
                (insert
                 (org-latex-guess-inputenc
                  (org-splice-latex-header
                   org-format-latex-header
                   (delq
                    nil
                    (mapcar
                     (lambda (el)
                       (unless (and (listp el) (string= "hyperref" (cadr el)))
                         el))
                     org-latex-default-packages-alist))
                   org-latex-packages-alist
                   nil))
                 (if fit "\n\\usepackage[active, tightpage]{preview}\n" "")
                 (if border (format "\\setlength{\\PreviewBorder}{%s}" border) "")
                 (if height (concat "\n" (format "\\pdfpageheight %s" height)) "")
                 (if width  (concat "\n" (format "\\pdfpagewidth %s" width))   "")
                 (if headers
                     (concat "\n"
                             (if (listp headers)
                                 (mapconcat #'identity headers "\n")
                               headers) "\n")
                   "")
                 (if fit
                     (concat "\n\\begin{document}\n\\begin{preview}\n" body
                             "\n\\end{preview}\n\\end{document}\n")
                   (concat "\n\\begin{document}\n" body "\n\\end{document}\n"))))))  <-- CHANGED two more closing parens
          (when (file-exists-p out-file) (delete-file out-file))
          (let ((transient-pdf-file (org-babel-latex-tex-to-pdf tex-file)))
            (cond
             ((string= "pdf" extension)
              (rename-file transient-pdf-file out-file))
             (imagemagick
              (org-babel-latex-convert-pdf
               transient-pdf-file out-file im-in-options im-out-options)
              (when (file-exists-p transient-pdf-file)
                (delete-file transient-pdf-file)))
             (t
              (error "Can not create %s files, please specify a .png or .pdf file or try the :imagemagick header argument"
                     extension))))))
        nil) ;; signal that output has already been written to file
    body))
```

As you can see, only  eight lines were added and one line was changed to add a couple of closing parens to balance the two opening parens, one for each `let` form (plus the indentation change to the block of code in-between).

It is a workaround, but I can hardly recommend it: it's not only ugly, but the lack of generality is disturbing: if you want to add another buffer-local variable, you have to modify the function to save the value of that variable and then set the value of a new variable of the same name with the old value. It is completely mechanical, but it is tedious and error prone.

If there was a way that we could query for all the buffer-local variables of the buffer, then we could write generic code to do the above transformation in a general way. That's why I suggested that you submit a bug report/enhancement request: I hope there is such a mechanism, but I have not researched it.

In the absence of a fix, you'll have to be satisfied with the above workaround - or perhaps a better, less ugly solution that you or somebody else here comes up with.